# subindex into a cell array of strings

Tags: matlab

I have a 6 x 3 cell (called strat) where the first two columns contain text, the last column has either 1 or 2.

I want to take a subset of this cell array. Basically select only the rows where the last column has a 1 in it.

I tried the following,

```
ff = strat(strat(:, 3), 1:2) == 1;
```

The error message is,

```
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

How can I index into a cell array?

Comment: Try `ff = strat([strat{:,3}]==1, 1:2);` or `ff = strat([strat{:,3}]==1, :);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell arrays are accessed through braces `{}` instead of parentheses `()`.  Then, as a 2nd subtlety, when pulling values out of a cell arrays, you need to gather them...for numerics you gather them into regular arrays using `[]` and for strings you gather them into a new cell array using `{}`.  Confusing, eh?

```
ff = { strat{ [strat{:,3}]==1 , 1:2 } };
```

Gathering into cell arrays this way can often give the wrong shape when you're done.  So, you might try something like this

```
ind = find([strat{:,3}]==1);  %find the relevant indices
ff = {{strat{ind,1}; strat{ind,2}}';  %this will probably give you the right shape
```